# Getting user's source IP address in events

Tags: box-api

Is there a way to get user's source IP address in the event notification parameterss from Box APIs.

So if a user created a folder, as part of "created" event notification, in addition to user-id and user's name, I've a need to know user's source IP address.

Answer (score 0):

This currently isn't available as a parameter on event notifications, but we may consider adding it in the future.

Comment: Is there any other way to know the source IP of the user's current session. I see that you have it in the user's activity reports.

Comment: Currently the admin_logs API (the one you're referring to) is the only place IP is exposed.